# How to improve this complex json object/array to a map with Inheritance code

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I would like to have a array of object (only 1 level) of this following json:

```
[
    {
        'family' : {
            'name' : 'Doe',
            'from' : 'Foo'
        },
        'couples' : [
            {
                'couple' : {
                    'man' : 'Joe',
                    'woman' : 'Jane'
                },
                'childrens' : [
                    {
                        'name' : 'Joseph',
                        'sex' : 'male'
                    },
                    {
                        'name' : 'Martin',
                        'sex' : 'male'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'couple' : {
                    'man' : 'Richard',
                    'woman' : 'Rose'
                },
                'childrens' : [
                    {
                        'name' : 'Rose',
                        'sex' : 'female'
                    },
                    {
                        'name' : 'Joe',
                        'sex' : 'male'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to leave all the childrens in one array (in this case of 4 elements) and each element has the `__proto__` updated for the parent element (the couple has the family and the children has the couple). Doing this I will be able to access the parents easily.

But I don't know if my solution is the best one or there is same other way to do this.

My thinking was do samething like this:

```
var childrensArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var family = json[i].family;
    var couples = json[i].couples;

    for (var j = 0; j < couples.length; j++) {
        var couple = couples[j].couple;

        var childrens = couples[j].childrens;
        for (var y = 0; y < childrens.length; y++) {
            var children = childrens[y];
            children.__proto__ = { couple : couple, family : family};

            childrensArr.push(children);
        } 
    }
}
```

But dosen't looks right all those arrays, sameone has same sugestion to improve this solution? (Without a framework if is possible rs).

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

A example using my code bellow.

```js
var json = [
    {
        'family' : {
            'name' : 'Doe',
            'from' : 'Foo'
        },
        'couples' : [
            {
                'couple' : {
                    'man' : 'Joe',
                    'woman' : 'Jane'
                },
                'childrens' : [
                    {
                        'name' : 'Joseph',
                        'sex' : 'male'
                    },
                    {
                        'name' : 'Martin',
                        'sex' : 'male'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'couple' : {
                    'man' : 'Richard',
                    'woman' : 'Rose'
                },
                'childrens' : [
                    {
                        'name' : 'Rose',
                        'sex' : 'female'
                    },
                    {
                        'name' : 'Joe',
                        'sex' : 'male'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

var childrensArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var family = json[i].family;
    var couples = json[i].couples;

    for (var j = 0; j < couples.length; j++) {
        var couple = couples[j].couple;

        var childrens = couples[j].childrens;
        for (var y = 0; y < childrens.length; y++) {
            var children = childrens[y];
            children.__proto__ = { couple : couple, family : family};

            childrensArr.push(children);
        } 
    }
}

console.log(childrensArr);
//It's possible to get the family attrs or the couple attrs
console.log(childrensArr[0].family.name);
```

P.S.: look the example, i'm able o acess the `childrensArr[0].family.name`

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the wanted result?

Comment: I edit the question. you can find the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/sy8xm4z5/

Comment: *i'm able o acess the childrensArr[0].family.name* - it's still unclear how should look the expected result

Comment: Yes, with my code you are. But I'm not happy with those "for's". My questions is how to improve it

Comment: btw, *children* is plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested approach for getting all children with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var data = [{ family: { name: 'Doe', from: 'Foo' }, couples: [{ couple: { man: 'Joe', woman: 'Jane' }, children: [{ name: 'Joseph', sex: 'male' }, { name: 'Martin', sex: 'male' }] }, { couple: { man: 'Richard', woman: 'Rose' }, children: [{ name: 'Rose', sex: 'female' }, { name: 'Joe', sex: 'male' }] }] }],
    children = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r.concat(a.couples.reduce(function (s, b) {
            return s.concat(b.children);
        }, r));
    }, []);

console.log(children);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Edit with `couple` property.

```js
var data = [{ family: { name: 'Doe', from: 'Foo' }, couples: [{ couple: { man: 'Joe', woman: 'Jane' }, children: [{ name: 'Joseph', sex: 'male' }, { name: 'Martin', sex: 'male' }] }, { couple: { man: 'Richard', woman: 'Rose' }, children: [{ name: 'Rose', sex: 'female' }, { name: 'Joe', sex: 'male' }] }] }],
    children = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r.concat(a.couples.reduce(function (s, b) {
            return s.concat(b.children.map(function (c) {
                return Object.assign({ couple: b.couple }, c);
            }));
        }, r));
    }, []);

console.log(children);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: you code looks better than mine, but the only point is the inheritance, added two lines in your code (you can find here: https://jsfiddle.net/8ad5rq8q/) the family and the couple. But is missing only change each child `__proto__` (thanks for the correction haha) like this: `children.__proto__ = { couple : couple, family : family};`

Comment: please add a wanted result. actually i see not the point ... (what is `__proto__` doing?)

Comment: In my example you can see the wanted result... What I'm looking for is a better implementation. In JS if you try to get a object attr which is not defined, he will look in the `__proto__` to see if the attr is present (It's a kind of inheritance). You can see simple example for the `__proto__`: https://jsfiddle.net/b3Le50jd/

Answer (score 0):

```
var childrens=family_json[0].couples.map(function(couple){
    return couple.childrens;
});
```

That map function will return only the childs from your JSON object

Comment: Yes I could, but doing this I have the problem with the parents ( look my comment the the first answer.)

Comment: To be clear: You want to access the parent from the child object?